# How has the Chinese Politburo's approach to governance and economic policy changed under Xi Jinping's leadership?

Tags: china, chinese-communist-party, xi-jinping

There has been a lot of discussion in the Western media about the change in the politburo's approach to governance in general, especially how China became a lot more assertive. The term wolf warrior diplomacy is often used to refer to this more confrontational governance that China adopted under Xi. Aside from this change, were there any other changes in the politburo's approach to governance and economic policy under Xi?